# Apache2 mod_fcgid can't get data from http client

Tags: php, apache, cgi, fastcgi

I have an Android apps which does a lot of uploads via HTTP POST to my server.
Server is running Ubuntu with Apache/2.2.17.

This domain which hosts the PHP script to receive the uploads, is running through mod_fcgid.

At the moment I have around up to 10k uploads per 24 hours with a total data of aprox 4GB in that time frame.

And now I get a lot of mod_fcgid errors. My logs are full of them.

```
(70007)The timeout specified has expired: mod_fcgid: can't get data from http client
(70014)End of file found: mod_fcgid: can't get data from http client
```

Any idea how to fix it?

My *fcgid.conf*:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  AddHandler    fcgid-script .fcgi
#  FcgidConnectTimeout 120

FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
FcgidIOTimeout 3600
FcgidConnectTimeout 3600
FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
FcgidIdleTimeout 9600
FcgidProcessLifeTime 9600

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is there any information on how log it's taking for the users to upload the files? You might need to extend the time before mod_fcgid.c timeout. Also, when are most of the users attempting to upload? if they are uploading too frequent in a short period, Apache could be hanging, it uses a lot of RAM for each connection, which takes away from the available RAM for the uploaded files.

Comment: I'm not sure where I would see how long it's taking for the users to upload the files. The users are spread out over the world basically, and the server is located in Asia. I have tried to change Apache and fcgid timeout settings, still getting all the errors. Some uploaded files show '(70014)End of file found: mod_fcgid: can't get data from http client' even for files that have been successfully uploaded.

Comment: test upload a large file.

Comment: Have tested to upload large files previously (512mb), no problem at all. Through the application, the maximum file size going for upload is ~20 mb.

Comment: Did you get around this issue? I have a similar issue on iOS

Answer (score 0):

If you can upload large file within the limit (60 minutes) doesn't mean everyone on GSM connection can. For 20 MB file, the uplink speed must be almost 6 kB/s. Increase `FcgidIOTimeout` to match the minimum you expect from your clients.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Have changed all Fcgid timeouts (calculated to average upload speed at 1 kB/s), problem still persists, and still have same amount of 70007 and 70014 errors in my logs. It's literally driving me crazy. No idea anymore what exactly is wrong, I feel I have tried it all.